# llvm exception handling failing when built to object and linked

Tags: gcc, llvm

I have some exception handling which works fine using the JIT. Now I am
producing object files and linking them, but the exception handling
tables seem to be missing. I call `_Unwind_RaiseException` and get
`_URC_END_OF_STACK` as a result.

I produce my object file using `TargetMachine::addPassesToEmitFile` and
then I link my resulting files with:

```
gcc -Wl,--eh-frame-hdr -o prog input.o
```

I'm sure I'm just missing some option to generate the Dwarf tables, but
I can't figure out what it is. For the JIT version I set
`JITExceptionHandling` and `JITEmitDebugInfo` on `TargetOptions`.

To check each step I also emitted an LL (LLVM-IR) file. I verified this has the landingpad/invoke intructiosn. I then use the `llc` tool and then GCC to link. This combination also doesn't produce the desired results.

Which option(s) am I missing to do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a problem in my personality function. It was not setting the correct selector and/or not returning the correct return value at times. The runtime JIT exception handler appears to operate differently, and thus the tests would pass in that run.